# Where does JVM store information of abstract classes implemented at runtime?

Tags: java, jvm, abstract-class, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM library in Java to extract information of a class from compiled .class file. Now I am not able to get information of abstract classes implemented at runtime. 
Where does JVM store information of abstract classes instantiated at runtime? Like below example.

```
public MockAbstractClass testForAbstract(){
    return new MockAbstractClass() {
        @Override
        void abstractMethod() {
            mockMethod();
        }
    }; }

static abstract class MockAbstractClass{
    abstract void abstractMethod();   }
```

Here object of MockAbstractClass is created at runtime in testForAbstract() Method, also class is implemented at runtime.

Comment: It's not "implemented in runtime". It's an anonymous inner class. Even if anonymous it actually has a name: if it's inside the class Foo, and if it's the first (or only) anonymous class its name is Foo$1. You can discover that yourself by storing the created object in a variable, and printing variable.getClass().

Comment: So above anonymous class would be stored in compiled class file?

Comment: Of course. The instructions to execute need to be stored somewhere.

Comment: Ok thank you very much!!

Comment: While such an inner class is not much different to a top level class, being stored in a class file, there are also classes truly generated at runtime, like lambda classes. But even then, things are not so much different; regardless of the actual source of a class, being loaded from disk or generated on the fly, they have to be in a byte buffer or array, to be passed to one of the `definedClass` methods in `ClassLoader`, `MethodHandles.Lookup`, or `Unsafe` to get into the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdas are an example where classes are generated at runtime.

The only way to access dynamically generated class is to store them via Instrumentation. There is a component which is called for every class defined by any means. You then need to store a reference to the byte code for those classes.  You could optimise this to not store classes there the byte code can be retrieved from the classloader.

NOTE: For lambdas you don't get the class name or class loader but you can read the byte code to get the class name.